# Dependency parsing for French with CoreNLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm trying to use Stanford CoreNLP for French texts. POS tagging and parsing works fine, but with my configuration, output dependencies do not make sense at all.

My command is

```
java -mx1g -cp "~/stanford-corenlp/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09/*" 
edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -props french.conf 
-file /tmp/file.txt -outputFormat text
```

where french.conf contains:

```
annotators = tokenize, ssplit, pos, depparse, parse
tokenize.language = fr
pos.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/french/french.tagger
parse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz
depparse.model = edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_French.gz
```

I'm using CoreNLP 3.6 with French models found [here](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/index.html#download). The log looks fine with that respect:

```
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator tokenize
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator ssplit
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator pos
Reading POS tagger model from edu/stanford/nlp/models/pos-tagger/french/french.tagger ... done [0,2 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator depparse
Loading depparse model file: edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/UD_French.gz ... 
PreComputed 100000, Elapsed Time: 1.43 (s)
Initializing dependency parser done [3,4 sec].
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP - Adding annotator parse
[main] INFO edu.stanford.nlp.parser.common.ParserGrammar -     Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/frenchFactored.ser.gz ... 
done [3,0 sec].
```

but here is the result with "Le chat mange la souris" (*the cat is eating the mouse*, with the same exact structure)

```
root(ROOT-0, chat-2)
det(chat-2, Le-1)
case(souris-5, mange-3)
det(souris-5, la-4)
nmod:mange(chat-2, souris-5)
punct(chat-2, .-6)
```

which is just nonsense; and this is not exceptional, I tested many sentences and always got this kind of output.
That's why I guess I'm using a bad configuration file.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you find a solution? @jpl

Answer (score 2):

For those that would be interested, Stanford CoreNLP has now updated their models and they work pretty well now.

Answer (score 1):

It's because CoreNLP dependency parser expects to get as input Universal Dependencies POS tags and the French POS tagger provided by CoreNLP outputs French Treebank POS tags.

I've made a patch that converts the French POS tagger output in order to get Universal Dependencies POS tags: https://github.com/askplatypus/CoreNLP/commit/e6215bdc5d4903bc3e2d2fb533da7e3938fa825f